# Unity - two human players, how to detect which player did most damage to AI enemy?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I truly apologize for I have no code to offer here.

I am completely stumped, I’m still a coding noob and trying to run a simple exercise to test a game mechanic idea via prototype.

I’ll use a simple example:

- 2 players vs. 2 AI enemies
- both enemy ai have 400 points of health
- both human players have guns that do 20 points of damage per trigger
  press.
- both enemies are dead after a quick battle.

I want to reward the player who did the most damage to the enemies.

This is what I am trying to achieve:
**How do I go about detecting, which player, did the most damage to the enemy AI?**

Any help would be appreciated, once I can grasp the concept of how to even go about doing this, I can then move forward on how to code it.

Thanks.

Comment: If who applied damage to something is important to you then you need to keep track of it somehow. You could have a List or Dictionary on each enemy to keep track of incoming damage and then query it to find who did the most when they die.

Comment: Would it not be easier to have the function/object which deals the damage report back to the player how much damage they have done and let the player store it?

Comment: Do you use multiplayer or just a two-man playing game in the console

Comment: Thank you guys, I will explore both avenues.

Comment: @JustARandomWibuuuu it will be multiplayer online

Comment: @RetiredNinja once I attach the list or dictionary to keep track of incoming damage - how do i go about detecting which player did the most of that damage? I ponder maybe using raycasts? that shoots out from the player, yet I still don’t see how the raycast can be used to provide the list or dictionary, a identifier of which player did “x amount” of damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too general - there are a lot of ways to do this. Let's stick to OOP: let's make the "damage" object (script, class), which contains the following info: damage amount, player id. Wheh player hits trigger, lets assume, the bullet prefab is instantiated. It has a script (MonoBehaviour) on it, called "DamageContainer". When you instantiate a bullet, you also create your "damage" object, set correct values, and put it into bullet's "damage container". Then, when bullet collides with enemy, you get this info from bullet. Damage amount you use to reduce enemy's health. For counting damage, you need the counter itself. It can be a static class, a scriptable object, singleton, or something else. Let's use a static class, which is not the best practice, but simplest one. You need a simple static class, called "DamageCounter", and containing two public fields: Player1Damage and Player2Damage. When bullet collides with enemy, you need to add dealt damage to proper field of "DamageCounter", depending of damage.PlayerId field.

And don't forget to reset static class values on start of each battle.

Comment: @Mykhalio Khadzhynov  Wow! Thank you! This is very in-depth, I see what you are saying, you’ve illustrated your theory clearly.  Please allow me to recap:   Essentially, the player id  (with damage amounts) this script which is attached to each instantiated bullet, via a object labeled damagecontainer (this produces the player data once hit is confirmed. We then have a counter for each player, when enemy dies, counter provides total damage values of each player. Brilliant sir! thank you. This GREATLY helps.

Comment: Happy to help. The idea of OOP is that everything is objects, and you can encapsulate any data inside the object. So, damage is object, containing data (shooter id, damage amount, damage type - ice, fire, etc.), and bullet just transfers this object from shooter to target.

Comment: Also, as I am thinking now, its not a good idea to use static class - it's better to implement counter inside enemy itself - if you only have a single enemy. Or, if there is many enemies, you better create counter as non-static, and give a reference on it to every enemy. Scriptable object fits well for it, you can just assign it to enemy's prefab.

Comment: Thank you, I will most definitely follow your advice - place counter inside the enemy.

Comment: @Mykhalio Khadzhynov I have heard much about OOP theory, but most of it was in bits and pieces or, my understanding of it was in bits and pieces not fully able to grasp the nuances.  However, by you showing me how to use game objects for what’s normally in the physical realm intangible, it makes soo much more sense now. I really appreciate you, your response has created in paradigm shift in my thought process.  Happy Holidays to you. Thank you again!